# Community Wiki still shows original poster

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, ios-app, community-wiki

On the iOS app, when commenting on a Community Wiki post, it still tells you who posted the answer.

> [image: bug image]

Personally, I tend to use CW to post posts with controversial statements so that people can't find out who posted them and judge me.

Therefore this kinda alarms me and presumably others who use CW for the same reason. Is this a bug or should this happen?

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 5s (Global)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.2 (Build 14F89)

Answer (score 9):

CW posts are not anonymous.  The original poster of any CW post is accessible *by design*.  It's not shown *as prominently*, more specifically, it's not necessarily shown directly in the user card, but that doesn't mean that it's *hidden*.  You can always, if nothing else, go to the revision history of any CW post and see which users made which contributions.

CW is not for posts that you want to be anonymous.  They're also not for posts that you think are controversial.  They're for posts that represent collaborative works from multiple people, in which the person that posted it isn't necessarily the original author of the content.  If that's not the case for a given post of yours, you shouldn't be making it a community wiki post.